# Linear x axis for bar chart chartjs

Tags: charts, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

I am using `chartjs 2.9.3`. I want to have linear scale for x axis for bar plots. It should work just like any linear scale of line plots representing negative, decimal, positive values.

I have managed to create almost similar scale [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-2-example-forked-rkp0d?file=/src/index.js) using this options.

```
 scales: {
    xAxes: [
      {
        type: "time",
        time: {
          parser: "Y",
          unit: "year",
          displayFormats: {
            year: "Y"
          }
        },
      }
    ]
  },
```

But it is not working for decimal values, when dataset has negative `x` values, it is just rounding off to integer and placing the bar at that position.

How can represent decimal values as well?

`Chartjs >=3.0.0` has introduced linear scale for bar plots. But this version has some other bugs in it so I am stuck with 2.9.3 version

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend to change the axis type to `time`, as this will introduce several other issues given that there are not "fractional times". And adding support for it is not that easy.

The best bet is to create your own labels with a custom function. For example:

```js
    const f = () => {
      let a = [];
      for (let n = -30; n <= 30; n++) {
        a.push(n / 100 + "");
      }
      return a;
    };
```

To generate from -3.00 to +3.00 (zeros representing decimal places). The bigger the numbers `30` and `100` the bigger the "resolution" of your linear scale.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-2-example-forked-26bbx?file=/src/index.js

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this.  But when x axis if of category, zoom with drag and panning the x axis does not work but on time scale it does work